# execute next request once the execution of first request is completed in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Let's assume I have an endpoint `/print`. Whenever a request is made to this endpoint, it executes a function `printSomething()`. While `printSomething()` is processing, if the user or another user hits this endpoint it will execute `printSomething()` again. If this occurs multiple times the method will be executed multiple times in parallel.

```
app.get('/print', (req, res) => {
  printSomething(someArguments);
  res.send('processing receipts');
});
```

The issue with the default behavior is that, inside `printSomething()` I create some local files which are needed during the execution of `printSomething()` and when another call is made to the `printSomething()` it will override those files, hence none of the call's return the desired result.

What I want to do is to make sure `printSomething()` execution is completed, before another execution of `printSomething()` is started. or to stop the current execution of `printSomething()` once a new request is made to the endpoint.

Comment: could you show us the function?

Answer (score 1):

You have different option based on what you need, how much request you expect to receive and what you do with those file you are creating

**Solution 1**

If you expect little traffic on this endpoint

you can add some unique key to `someArguments` based on your req or randomly generated and create the files you need in a different directory

**Solution 2**

If you think that it will cause some performance issue you have to create some sort of queue and worker to handle the tasks.

In this way you can handle how many task can be executed simultaneously

Comment: I don't have lots of requests, maybe 10 request per day at max. I am using an ejs template to create an html file then generate pdf for that html file.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop the previous execution of ``printSomething()`` once a new execution is started?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a REST system with distributed calls this sounds problematic. Usually you don't want one request to block another.
If the Order of operation is crucial (FIFO) then it looks like a classing Queue problem.

There are many different way to implement the Queue, you could use an array or something or implement a singleton class extending eventEmitter.

```
const myQueue = new Q()
const crypto = require('crypto');

const route = (req,res) => {
  const uniqeID =crypto.randomUUID()
  myQueue.once(uniqeID, (data) =>{
    res.send(data)
  })
  myQueue.process(uniqID, req.someDaTa)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `app.locals`, as the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals) suggest: `Once set, the value of app.locals properties persist throughout the life of the application`.

You need to use `req.app.locals`, something like

```js
req.app.locals.isPrinting = true;
----
//Then check it
if (req.app.locals.isPrinting)
```

`req.app.locals` is the way [express helps](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.app) you access `app.locals`